# SharePoint Online PowerShell cmdlets: Get Group's Ids

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-online, groups, export

I need to export my site collection's groups from sharepoint online. I have create the following script to get all the info but I cannot retrieve the group's Id. I am talking about this ID
https://xxxxxx.sharepoint.com/_layouts/userdisp.aspx?**ID=28**

```
Get-SPOSiteGroup -Site https://xxxxxx.sharepoint.com | select * | Format-Table -Wrap -AutoSize | Out-File C:\Scripts\ExportedGroups.txt -Force -Width 4096
```

The script will return info on the following:

- LoginName
- Title
- OwnerLoginName
- OwnerTitle
- Users Roles

but no ID. Is it possible to retrieve that as well? Maybe is there a sharepoint list with all the users/groups I could export instead?

Comment: try this one"Get-SPOSiteGroup -Site https://xxxxxx.sharepoint.com" if you get the ID or Get-SPOSiteGroup -Site https://xxxxxx.sharepoint.com | Select ID

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cmdlet [Get-SPOSiteGroup](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp161385%28v=office.15%29.aspx) returns the collection of `SPOSiteGroup` objects but `Group ID` is not exposed in this object.

---

### Invoking SharePoint Online REST requests from PowerShell

The following REST request could be used to return site collection groups:

```
https://contoso.sharepoint.com/_api/web/sitegroups
```

You could invoke REST requests in SharePoint Online using [Invoke-RestSPO.ps1](https://gist.github.com/vgrem/9255180) PS Script . Please refer [this post](http://blog.vgrem.com/2014/02/27/working-with-the-sharepoint-online-rest-service-via-powershell/) for a more details.

Example: print site groups information:

```
$results = .\Invoke-RestSPO.ps1 -Url "https://contoso.sharepoint.com/_api/web/sitegroups" -UserName "username@contoso.onmicrosoft.com"
$results | select Title, id | Format-Table -Wrap -AutoSize
```

Comment: This is great. Wish I could award you something more than just one tick. This thing will come in handy in so many ways!

Comment: Thanks! :)  Indeed, it makes available  the whole SharePoint REST API for usage from PS.  In my opinion SharePoint Online cmdlets covers very limited functionality

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you could use [Get-SPOGroups](https://sharepointonlineautomationcmdlets.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Get-SPOGroups)

Here's an example

```
$ctx = Get-SPOContext url username password
Get-SPOGroups -Web $ctx.Web
```

This will give you a list of groups and ids in the rootweb. 
If you need users there is also [Get-SPOWebUsers](https://sharepointonlineautomationcmdlets.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Get-SPOWebUsers)

Example

```
$ctx = Get-SPOContext url username password
Get-SPOWebUsers -Web $ctx.Web
```